# Decision variable must lie in union of multiple disjoint intervals

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In my Linear Program, I'm trying to express that a decision variable $x \in R$ can only lie in certain intervals, e.g. $x \in [0,2] \cup [5,8] \cup [9,15]$.
I'm aware of that you can model ***either** constraint 1 OR constraint 2* with a Big M trick (e.g. [explained here in section 7.3](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf) and [asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849319/forbidden-range-for-a-linear-programming-variable/849532#849532?newreg=a25368062bb7429d98562f70450086c7), but do not see directly how this could solve my question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $[a_i,b_i]$ is the $i$-th interval then for a binary variable $z_i$ the inequality

$$a_iz_i-(1-z_i)M\leq x\leq b_iz_i+(1-z_i)M$$

gives $x\in[a_i,b_i]$  when $z_i=1$ and is "free" ($x\in [-M,M]$) when $z_i=0$. So a family of such constraints together with

$$\sum z_i= 1$$

models the membership in a union of intervals $x\in\bigcup_i[a_i,b_i]$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

With the same binary variables $z_i$ as in @MichalAdamaszek's answer, a tighter formulation is
\begin{align}
\sum_i a_i z_i \le x &\le \sum_i b_i z_i \\
\sum_i z_i &= 1
\end{align}

Comment: Nice answer. Used it at http://ask.cvxr.com/t/multi-bound-variable/9837/3