# linearizing non-strict inequality If.. else conditional constraint that includes decision variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I would like to linearize a conditional constraint as follow:

**0 <= x1 <= 1**.

If **0 <= x1 < 1**, then **x2 = 1**, else **x2 = 0**.

I find it very difficult because it is not a typical **If...then** constraint. Any suggestions or answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

JZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant.  You can linearize the relationship as follows:
$$1-x_2 \le x_1 \le 1-\epsilon x_2$$

Just check the two cases for $x_2 \in\{0,1\}$.

More generally, if you want to enforce $x_1 \in [a,b] \cup [c,d]$, you can use
$$a x_2 + c (1-x_2) \le x_1 \le b x_2 + d (1-x_2).$$
Your problem corresponds to $(a,b,c,d)=(0,1-\epsilon,1,1)$.

Even more generally, see [Decision variable must lie in union of multiple disjoint intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961000/decision-variable-must-lie-in-union-of-multiple-disjoint-intervals/3962028#3962028).

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: I would like to know more about the procedure for linearizing such logical constraints. Could you elaborate on how you did that or recommend some references? I think showing the way will be even more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I added more detail to the answer.  You can learn more by reading posts from https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linearization.